# Getting headaches using Firebase 9, Redux Toolkit and Typescript in React. 'dispatch' somehow has type 'never'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to migrate  an existing but old project to newer technologies, and specifically those mentioned in the title. I have little experience with Typescript, none with redux-toolkit and I'm used to Firebase v8 but migrating to v9 for modularity.

So, in my firebase realtime database I have a users table that I want to fetch some informations from, and I'm trying to achieve this through `createAsyncThunk` from `@reduxjs/toolkit` but with bad luck to this point. Standard actions are processed the way they're supposed to so it's definitely the thunk thing creating problems. I'm attaching some code:

**The thunk**

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { ref, onValue, DataSnapshot, child, DatabaseReference } from "firebase/database";
import { usersDb } from '../Firebase/utils';
import { MyBrandAppUser } from "../Types/MyBrandAppUser";

export const fetchMyBrandAppUser = createAsyncThunk('users/fetchMyBrandAppUser', async (uid: string, thunkAPI) => {
    const userEntry: DatabaseReference = child(usersDb, uid);
    let theUser: MyBrandAppUser | null = null;

    await onValue(userEntry, (snapshot: DataSnapshot) => {
        if( snapshot.exists() ) 
            theUser = <MyBrandAppUser>snapshot.val();
        else
            return null;
    }, 
    (err: Error) => {
        thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err)
    });
    
    return theUser;  
})
```

I'm afraid this first part won't achieve what I assume it should since that `onValue` won't return a promise, but that's another topic for another time maybe.

**The store**

```
import { configureStore, EnhancedStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from '../Features/Auth';
import logger from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export const store: EnhancedStore = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: userReducer,
    },

    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false,
    }).concat(logger).concat(thunk)
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

**My users slice:**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
import { WritableDraft } from "immer/dist/internal";
import { UserState } from "../../Types/Redux/States";
import { fetchMyBrandAppUser  } from "../../API/fetchUser";
import { MyBrandAppUser } from "../../Types/MyBrandAppUser";

const initialState: UserState = {
    firebaseUser: undefined,
    myBrandAppUser: undefined,
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "users",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setFirebaseUser: (state: WritableDraft<UserState>, action:PayloadAction<User | null>) => {
            state.firebaseUser = action.payload;
        }, 
    }, 

    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(fetchMyBrandAppUser.fulfilled, (state: WritableDraft<UserState>, action) => {
            state.myBrandAppUser = action.payload;
        })
    }
})

export const { setFirebaseUser } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

But now if I try to call `dispatch(fetchMyBrandAppUser(userID))` typescript won't let me, with the following complaint:

1. For a regular action: `Argument of type '{ payload: User | null; type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)`
2. For thunk actions: `Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<null, string, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the `EnhancedStore` type on the store, for future reference.